# Geometry Nodes: how do I use the location of a point as the position for Set Handle Positions node?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

in geometry nodes I'm trying to make an alien sunflower type plant, I have a dish that copies the rotation of the sun, and a point attached behind the dish that moves with it. basically I have everything working how I want it to except that the top of the stem doesn't look like it's attached to the base of the dish.[image: the node set up] I made the point behind the dish because I was hoping I could use that point's location as the position of the curve handle, but I can not get it to work. the setup I have currently lets me manually move the set handle position with the offset so I think something is wrong with my transfer attribute node set up[image: how I want it to look]
sorry my nodes are kind of a mess. I've been all over the internet looking for a solution, I can only find confusing explanations for how the position and transfer attribute nodes work just saying to use them together. any help would be great thanks

Comment: In order for your question to be answered quickly and satisfactorily, please be kind enough to share your blend file with us (https://blend-exchange.com/). This will avoid misunderstandings, allow for faster and more accurate answers, and not force anyone to rebuild the node tree and possibly provide an answer that may not be what solves your problem. Thank you!

Comment: ...but just a basic tip that might help you: Maybe it helps if you switch the node `Transfer Attribute` from *Float* to *Vector*.